# symfony: how to reference images generated using LiipImagineBundle when not having web/ as index directory

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I have installed `LiipImagineBundle` to apply filters to my images, on my localhost.
It works perfect. It generates images like `my_project/web/media/cache/my_widen/images/products/image.jpg`, that I show using this:

```
<img src="{{ ('/images/products/' ~ product.imageName) | imagine_filter('my_widen') }}">
```

The problem: in my remote shared server, the index directory is not `my_project/web`, as I defined in my local machine, but just `my_project/`. Since I can not change it to `my_project/web`, I can not see the images at `web/media/cache...` unless I use this:

What should I do to show them correctly in both machines (local and remote) using the same code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to change the `data_root` in the bundle's configuration. Read the [configuration chapter of the documentation](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration.md) for more information.